# Keycloak identity brokering (to Azure AD) blocked by corporate proxy on authorization_code exchange

Tags: proxy, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, keycloak

I have `AzureAD` as external OIDC provider registered at `Keycloak`. `Keycloak` redirects client authorization requests to `AzureAD` for providing the authorization. `Keycloak` is running on my workstation behind a corporate proxy, the corresponding Azure AD is hosted in the public internet. I'm able to connect to Azure AD with `Postman` from my local workstation.

[image]

The authorization via `AzureAD` works as expected (The user is prompted to put in her/his credentials and accept the consent). After successful authorization `AzureAD` responds with an authorization_code to the defined `Keycloak` return-url:

```
http://localhost:5000/auth/realms/lsp-api/broker/ms-azure-ad/endpoint?code=AQABAAIAAADX8GCi6Js6SK82TsD2Pb7rL__pDRDcKAqDqyTeTdzmbC9n3kcz5flc0q7zDRbK-WVLUpcUU65tWSh9C-opFiwtMZOACwGLQDgh4y4ScLW-dUGN7g3Ad3_aBqK-uHPgS3uKM1OlAIeSw3NSl1DMTKhH7SGQRGITP6ARIrCL9snqNRDUbHvhfKVlLMxmJTUk0bKDIT3PzM4nBSd1NwdXc9VZ9cCFnRMjlKfpRUx3guo-58tgSL5Vsaf8TvKg8B5TSYbiDzS49epFsU0Eg_PBs1JU4Q-8vOrN_wlV1zs1IUDYbUv8EdlMdqJkaT-nBTv-4Ab2Jf3X39u4m666kvcWmezGJ-NkjPqaOSK6eglWJfjW_z9-vHFQl6F9JxdCIlGbolyZyUpo0-a0LlnVVg2gyl1wJEOSnv5RvhmTZOqa1qWxZNsyG15JeQBkcK-J0XzWmn8CaeqzsJwFlNwkpzK_XaZW-KIsWayZ0Rz2HdDYh3Mre2I4uRmDyoQLiP60lYDaYowZZ11jSBy_87vFL2alK-5sGyUajs6kODfsoSlEGHhWJeHMiC2-jYm0gMNTQIvUMYpLJRpgKX6v3n-E3Q7ZlYD_VAWOnDZBCR5iaTsUOxuXN6CiC4p01N47c4QG4Y8A9lTbVXDvVcxSBz8H7uM5DfawFGUKpSCobI9V1XKnyw1R8UXTObqmEq8gA4jBzaRZb89qAnlZ6X-w39LbLWE7MUlL0Ok8LP-7omQlVei6AdEMfrIaHNIBUFimHLgKjiqcG2ogAA&state=FevrPXHHXkICQjFEYJ_3ZyvfZ2Y9E6iM5foCcOvk5C8.jXAAgdz4mnA.lsp-api&session_state=8cb0539a-b775-4de6-b334-5cb24caeb685
```

[image]

This response is sent with the status code `502, Bad Gateway`. Furthermore the error-msg "Unexpected error when authenticating with Identity Provider" is displayed.

I already tried to send the returned `authorization_code` manually to the `AzureAD` `/token` endpoint and I received the `access_token` and the `id_token` back. So the problem seems to be the response-handling on the `Keycloak`-side.

**Expected behavior would have been:**

1. `AzureAD` responds to `Keycloak` with the `authorization_code`
2. `Keycloak` is able to exchange the `authorization_code` for an `access_token` (mb. in addition an `id_token`)

**What does not work:**

`Keycloak` is not able to exchange the authorization_code for an `access_token`, but throws the "Unexpected error when authenticating with Identity Provider" error-message.

**Keycloak setup:**

Keycloak Version: 4.1.0.Final

[image]

The `AzureAD` `Reply-URL` is set to http://localhost:5000/auth/realms/lsp-api/broker/ms-azure-ad/endpoint .

### Edit

I did some more research and found out that this is probably a corporate proxy issue. The proxy is situated between `Keycloak` (running on my machines localhost) and `AzureAD`. So how do I set the proxy for `Keycloaks` Identity Brokering? The relevant `Keycloak` logs:

```
org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider] (default task-122) Failed to make identity provider oauth callback: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to login.microsoftonline.com:443 [login.microsoftonline.com/40.112.64.25, login.microsoftonline.com/104.41.216.18, login.microsoftonline.com/104.41.216.16] failed: Connection refused: connect
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.makeRequest(SimpleHttp.java:185)
    at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asResponse(SimpleHttp.java:154)
    at org.keycloak.broker.provider.util.SimpleHttp.asString(SimpleHttp.java:146)
    at org.keycloak.broker.oidc.AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider$Endpoint.authResponse(AbstractOAuth2IdentityProvider.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:140)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:295)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:249)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:138)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:107)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invokeOnTargetObject(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:133)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceLocatorInvoker.invoke(ResourceLocatorInvoker.java:101)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:406)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:213)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:228)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:56)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:51)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSessionServletFilter.doFilter(KeycloakSessionServletFilter.java:90)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1508)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:326)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:812)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
    ... 74 more
```

Comment: Not related, answer maybe here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51787942/3797368 
Can You please provide example how are you mapping claims ? And how is your client in keycloak set ? 
I am trying to map groups from JWT to Keycloak
Thanks

Comment: In the `Keycloak` admin console you just have to go to your registered identity broker and create a new claims-mapper there. It is documented here: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.0/server_admin/topics/identity-broker/mappers.html

Comment: have you resolved it? Can you please share How you have configured AzureAD as external OIDC provider at Keycloak

Comment: I was not able to solve the issue yet. You can follow the Keycloak doc on how to configure an identity broker: https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_identity_broker

Comment: I have the similar issue (login with google).  I think it related to proxy.  Did you have a solution now?

Comment: unfortunately not. It seems like you can not configure a Proxy for the outbound calls of the used module.

Answer (score 0):

This exception means that there is no service listening on the IP/port you are trying to connect to:

1. You are trying to connect to the wrong IP/port.
2. You have not started your server.
3. Your server is not listening for connections.
4. On Windows servers, the listen backlog queue is full.

You can try to replace the localhost with your IP address. Also do ensure there's no firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've already checked your suggested points of failure. 1 -> It is the correct IP, I was able to get the desired response there with postman. 2 -> server is running, ms azure server is also up and running. 3, 4 -> see 1...

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set proxy for JVM like

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.example.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've already tried to set the proxy for the JVM like this but it did not change the behavior... Anyhow the identity provider oauth callback for trading the `auth_code` for an `auth_token` seems not to be affected.

Comment: `-Dhttps.proxyPort= and -Dhttps.proxyPort=` for https